# Is it possible to use Digest Authentication for network images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, authentication, hash, snapshot, onvif

I am trying to determine if it is possible to use digest authentication to get a JPEG image from an Onvif url in flutter. I can get the RTSP stream working by adding the username/password as part of the URL (rtsp://username:password@thecameraurl).

However, in Postman getting the snapshot JPEG requires Digest Authentication, not basic. I am looking for solutions to use the same Digest Authentication but with a network image (in Flutter).

I have tried using CachedNetworkImage with a basic auth header, but alas this doesn't work as the Onvif JPEG requires Digest Authentication.

Comment: Have you tried using the exact same URL syntax with digest auth? I see no reason for the URL syntax to change.

Comment: The issue is I am unsure how to use Digest Auth headers with a network image in Flutter; if I send <http://username:password@thejpegurl> with Postman, or with Flutter, I get the response that my client is not authorized. To get it to work with Postman I have to use Digest Auth, but I am unsure how to do the same within Flutter.